# How can I exclude certain values from a column in a query search

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to exclude any entry that is not mapped in a query search, I have seen an example online but I think I am barking up the wrong tree.

[image]

```
SELECT 
LocationID, LocationAddress 
FROM tblLawncare 
WHERE ISNULL(Hide,0) = 0 
AND LocationAddress 
IS NOT Not Mapped  
ORDER BY LocationID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
LocationID, LocationAddress 
FROM tblLawncare 
WHERE ISNULL(Hide,0) = 0 
AND LocationAddress <> 'not mapped' 
ORDER BY LocationID
```

Although I'm not sure what your `WHERE ISNULL(Hide, 0) = 0` is supposed to be doing. What is `Hide`?

Comment: this is a relative example I am pulling from a real database

Comment: `ISNULL(Hide,0) = 0` is way of saying `(Hide IS NULL OR Hide = 0)`

Answer (score 2):

You mean this?

```
SELECT 
LocationID, LocationAddress 
FROM tblLawncare 
WHERE ISNULL(Hide,0) = 0 
AND LocationAddress <> 'not mapped'
ORDER BY LocationID
```